# Не получается получить доступ к странице CURL

Tags: curl

```
// тестовые данные
$vk_id = "id111111111"; $pass = "12345";

// Авторизация
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://turboliker.ru/login/get_profl_id.php');

$post_login = "link=https://vk.com/".$vk_id;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_login);
$html = curl_exec($curl);

if($html == "1") {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://turboliker.ru/login/login_by_pass.php');

     $post_pass = "pass=".$pass;
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_pass);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,      $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt'); // записываем файл с куками

    $result = curl_exec($curl); // вернёт 1, если авторизация прошла успешно
}

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt'); // посылаем куки

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://turboliker.ru/');
$html = curl_exec($curl); // должна появиться страница для авторизированного пользователя

curl_close($curl);

echo $html;
```

Пытаюсь получить доступ к станице, которая показывается только авторизированным, но никак не удаётся. возможно неверно передаю куки, подскажите пожалуйста.

Содержимое куки файла:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.turboliker.ru    TRUE    /   FALSE   1506330411  __cfduid    de84b2cbfc1a2db75fd0998437ebcb4191474794411
turboliker.ru   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   p5umk93864c364cs5fc60ucsq5
```

Comment: покажите куки-файл и убедитесь, что он достается по корректному пути.

Comment: @mkardakov добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раскомментировал строку `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cookie.txt');` и всё заработало.
Только учусь)